# Mysql left join with or condition for fallback language

Tags: mysql, left-join, coalesce, fallback

I have 2 table 'countries' and 'countries_lang'

```
+------+--------------+-----------------+
| id   | region_code  | sub_region_code |
+------+--------------+-----------------+
|    1 | 142          | 034             |
|    2 | 150          | 154             |
|    3 | 002          | 015             |
+------+--------------+-----------------+

+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| id  | pid  | lang_code | lang_name | lang_capital |
+-----+------------------+-----------+--------------+
|   1 | 1    | en_GB     |Canada     | Ottawa       |
|   2 | 1    | de_DE     |Kanada     | Ottawa       |
|   3 | 2    | en_GB     |Italy      | Rome         |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

`en_GB` is the fallback language so my goal is to join countries_lang passing a lnaguage if not in table return the fallback language value

example:

selected language is `de_DE`

```
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id   | region_code  | lang_name       | lang_capital |
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    1 | 142          | Kanada          | Ottawa       +
|    3 | 150          | Italy           | Rome         + (fallback language)
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I tried:

```sql
    Select * FROM countries AS c 
     LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT pid, 
            COALESCE(
                (
                    SELECT lang_name FROM countries_lang WHERE lang_code = 'de_DE' AND pid = c.id
                ),
                (
                    SELECT lang_name FROM countries_lang WHERE lang_code = 'en_GB' AND pid = c.id

                )
            ) AS cl_name,
            COALESCE(
                (
                    SELECT lang_capital FROM countries_lang WHERE lang_code = 'de_DE' AND pid = c.id
                ),
                (
                    SELECT lang_capital FROM countries_lang WHERE lang_code = 'en_GB' AND pid = c.id

                )
            ) AS cl_capital
        FROM countries_lang
    ) AS cl 

    ON (c.id = cl.pid)
```

but return `c.id` UNKNOWN Column

Any suggestion ? are 2 days that I am making test to solve this problem

Thanks to all !!!

EDIT

I tried in this way too but return always the fallback languages value

```sql
    Select * FROM countries AS c
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT pid, lang_name, lang_code FROM countries_lang WHERE lang_code = 'de_DE' AND lang_code IS NOT NULL OR lang_code = 'en_GB'
    ) AS cl ON 
    c.id = cl.pid
```

Comment: It is not clear how to join your two tables, and also it is not clear why your expected output shows English when in fact there is already an entry.

Comment: how do you define which is the fallback?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why the join is not clear, cut the middle part

Comment: Select * FROM countries AS c LEFT JOIN ( SELECT pid FROM countries_lang) AS cl  ON (c.id = cl.pid)

Comment: @AivanMonceller with a select in session by the way consider in this example as a constant de_DE my question is how to get a value en_GB as fallback language if is selected de_DE

Comment: will there always be 2 maximum languages listed? How about if there 2 languages en_GB, en_US then I select de_DE then which will be the fallback?

Comment: @AivanMonceller the fallback language is set as default is always en_GB anyway that is not the problem.. the question is how to get en_GB value if the de_DE value is NULL

Comment: I was asking because if that is what you wanted to achieve then this schema is incorrect , that is why you are tryinig to do some hack with SQL

Comment: Thanks got your point, but the schema is correct and work with more than 2 languages. default languages used as fallback and selected in session. table A id -> table B parent_id, lang_code, name. I know that is a mix with left join and coalesce.. coalesce get the first value not null so passing the first as selection languages and as second the default language if the first is null get the second else the first.. but in my example the problem is that I need to pass the id in pid but give me error :(

Comment: Where's `ez_countries_lang` table? How does it look like?

Comment: @Tin Mistake during the copy, edited. Thanks

Comment: I think there is one inconsistency between your result example and your query. In your query `c.id = cl.pid`. Does it mean `cl.pid` is foreign key to `c.id`? In your result, for Rome, `3 | 002 | Italy | Rome` instead of `3 | 150 | Italy | Rome`. So what's incorrect - your query join or your result example?

Comment: @Tim You are totaly correct by the way the query work good, I wrote the question at 5 am and make some typing mistake. Thank you for your attention. The relation beetwen the 2 table it's simple ID -> PID no foreign key. I joined with 3 table and coalesce and work perfect I don't understand here that the relation is 2 table how to get the en_GB value when the de_DE is null.

Comment: My thinking is too use coalesce passing before the selected language (de_DE) andf than the fallback (en_GB) the problem that I can't pass the countries id into the coalesce SELECT unkown column. LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT pid, lang_code, 
 COALESCE(
  (
   SELECT  lang_name FROM countries_lang 
   WHERE countries_lang.pid = countries.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'de_DE'
  ),
  (
   SELECT  lang_name FROM countries_lang 
   WHERE countries_lang.pid = countries.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'en_GB'
  )
 ) AS lang_name
 FROM countries_lang
) AS countries_lang ON 
(c.id = cl.pid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have limited knowledge of what your schema logic is and what exactly you are trying to query. Here is what I can come up with based on your given information. Let me know how it goes.

Query:

```
select cl.id, c.region_code, cl.lang_name, cl.lang_capital
from countries_lang cl 
join countries c on c.id = cl.pid
left join 
(select cl.id, cl.pid
from countries_lang cl 
join countries c on c.id = cl.pid and cl.lang_code = 'de_DE') fcl on cl.pid = fcl.pid 
where cl.id = fcl.id or fcl.id is null
```

Result:

```
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id   | region_code  | lang_name       | lang_capital |
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
|    2 | 142          | Kanada          | Ottawa       +
|    3 | 150          | Italy           | Rome         + 
+------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I don't think that the schema is not clear and my goal si clear join the second table and if the value of selected language (de_DE) for example is null show the default language en_GB. By the way in your code where you pass the default language en_GB ?

Comment: Hi Tin I checked well your code and your solution is better about performance respect coalesce. ;)

Comment: how could a join (select <use outer column here>) work, considering MYSQL is solving JOINS first, then selects?

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution and hope be helpfull for somebody!

```
SELECT * FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT jc.id, countries_lang.pid, countries_lang.lang_code,

    COALESCE(
        (
            SELECT lang_name FROM countries_lang 
            WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'de_DE'

        ),
        (
            SELECT lang_name FROM countries_lang 
            WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'en_GB'

        )
    ) AS coal_lang_name,

    COALESCE(
        (
            SELECT lang_capital FROM countries_lang 
            WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'de_DE'

        ),
        (
            SELECT lang_capital FROM countries_lang 
            WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = 'en_GB'

        )
    ) AS coal_lang_capital

    FROM countries_lang

    join countries jc on jc.id = countries_lang.pid
) AS cl ON 
(c.id = cl.pid)
```

For apply to all the languages just need to set 2 session variable one for fallback_language and one for selected language

example

$fallback_lang = $_SESSION['en_GB']; or any others
$lang = $_SESSION['de_DE']; or any other -> get from a select

and change in the above code

first coalesce
WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = '$lang'

second coalesce
WHERE countries_lang.pid = jc.id AND countries_lang.lang_code = '$fallback_lang'

COALESCE get the first value that is not NULL so before the selected than the fallback.

Cheers!!